# Mercurial and mysql

Tags: mysql, mercurial, revision

I'm using Mercurial for revision control of few projects. I have Mercurial installed both on my VPS and on my local machine. I push changes from my local machine to the remote server. Everything is okay.

However, I make sometimes changes to the database (mySql) and I need to update the database back and forth so that I keep the remote and local versions in sync (using phpmyAdmin).

Isn't there a solution to push changes to mysql like push changes to my remote repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Database deployment is a pain.  The usual solution is to use a tool to look at your source control descrption of the database (as a set of SQL scripts) and the target database and generate/apply a script to make the two match.

Some tools that do this are:

- [dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/)  (free)
- [DB Ghost](http://www.innovartis.co.uk/)
- [Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)
- [Redgate MySQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-compare/) (free for non-commercial)
- [Visual Studio Database Projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/) (SSDT)

I'm sure there are more.

Comment: Great answer, there are a couple of tools I was not aware of. Surprisingly, this must one of the few contexts where poorly written custom scripts tend to be better than available third-party tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Database Project](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-projects.html) (and Schema/Data Comparer) tools in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).